# ax.set_xlim3d has no effect in Matplotlib with ax.plot_wireframe

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having a conceptual problem with my data constraining boundary conditions for a wireframe plot in python. Could anyone explain to me where I have gone wrong?

I would like the boundaries to be constrained between -1.0 < x < 1.2, 0 < y < 0.25 and -0.6 < z < 0.2

```
    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='3d')

    def log_OIII_Hb_NII(log_NII_Ha, eps=0):
        return 1.19 + eps + 0.61 / (log_NII_Ha - eps - 0.47)
    def log_OIII_Hb_OI(log_OI_Ha, eps=0):
        return 1.33 + eps + 0.73 / (log_OI_Ha - eps + 0.59)
    def log_OIII_Hb_SII(log_SII_Ha, eps=0):
        return 1.30 + eps + 0.72 / (log_SII_Ha - eps - 0.32)

    NII = np.linspace(-2.0, 0.35)

    ax.set_xlim3d(-1.0, 1.2)
    ax.set_ylim3d( 0.0, 0.25)
    ax.set_zlim3d(-0.6, 0.2)

    ax.plot_wireframe(NII, 0, log_OIII_Hb_NII(NII))
    ax.plot_wireframe(NII, 0, log_OIII_Hb_NII(NII,  0.1))
    ax.plot_wireframe(NII, 0, log_OIII_Hb_NII(NII, -0.1))

    ax.plot_wireframe(NII, 0.1, log_OIII_Hb_NII(NII))
    ax.plot_wireframe(NII, 0.1, log_OIII_Hb_NII(NII,  0.1))
    ax.plot_wireframe(NII, 0.1, log_OIII_Hb_NII(NII, -0.1))

    ax.plot_wireframe(NII, 0.2, log_OIII_Hb_NII(NII))
    ax.plot_wireframe(NII, 0.2, log_OIII_Hb_NII(NII,  0.1))
    ax.plot_wireframe(NII, 0.2, log_OIII_Hb_NII(NII, -0.1))

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question correct I think that you finding that using the `ax.set_xlim3d` only restricts the axis and not the actual data itself. This is contrary to what occurs with `matplotlibs` *normal* 2D plots where setting the limits also restricts the actual data that is displayed.

Here is an example:

[image]

On the left I restrict the data using `ax1.set_xlim3d(0.0, 10.0)` which limits the axes but not the actual data. On the right I restrict the actual data itself.

If this is your problem then how you fix it will depend what exactly `NII, log_OIII_Hb_NII(NII),...` is (if in future you can, provide some test data people can use) and how you generate it.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143493/set-xlim-set-ylim-set-zlim-commands-in-matplotlib-fail-to-clip-displayed-data) seems to contain a relevant method.

Comment: Hey Greg. That is exactly the problem I am having. I have updated my first post to contain the information you feel you might need e.g. NII, log_OIII_Hb_NII etc...